# How can I provide a plaintext RSS feed?

Tags: rss

I've noticed that consuming our RSS feed on platforms that don't allow raw html (e.g bots announcing posts on chatrooms) just leads to mess.   We could just tell these consumers to strip html themself, but I'd rather be able to point them to a plaintext only RSS feed.

Whats the easiest way to offer an RSS feed that is plaintext only?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filters `the_content_feed` and `the_excerpt_rss` to decode & strip HTML:

```
function wpse_311515_plain_text( $content ) {
    $content = wp_strip_all_tags( $content );
    $content = html_entity_decode( $content, ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) );

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wpse_311515_plain_text' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss',  'wpse_311515_plain_text' );
```